# GlobalPlatform initiation mode implicit

Tags: implicit, javacard

I'am programming the differents implementations of globalplatform scp01 and scp02 on Javacard and I've found a problem.

Can someone explain me how is the mechanism of secure channel initiation on mode implicit?

In the spec I've found perfectly described the explicit way, (pag. 214, E.1.2.1 Explicit Secure Channel Initiation, with an awesome graphic), but the implicit form is very brief...

What are the steps I have to follow to do it correctly??

Thanks

Comment: Overly broad question. Maybe take a look at other GP implementations? There is a Java library on sourceforge.

Comment: I finally decided not implement implicit initiation because it is obsolete and it will be eliminate in future reviews of GP. Thanks anyway.